# Errors deleting printers

Tags: printing, cups-lpd

I have a bunch of network printers that were auto-discovered that I am trying to remove, but unable to do so.

When I first created this workstation, I plugged it into the network before editing CUPS so it auto-discovered a bunch of printers. I ended up editing `cups-browsed.conf` to have the values of `BrowseRemoteProtocols none` and `BrowseProtocols none`.

Now, under my control-center > printers, I show a list of printers. If I try to remove it via the GUI, it'll go away momentarily. But if I close and then re-open the GUI, it'll be there. The error that I get when trying to remove it is:

`(gnome-control-center:7193): printers-cc-panel-WARNING **: 09:39:01.516: cups-pk-helper: removing of printer ANTICOAG_AirPrint_e7_fc_5e_e7_fc_5e_e7_fc_e7_e7_fc_5e_ failed: client-error-not-found`

If I try to use the CUPS GUI at http://127.0.0.1:631/, there is nothing listed under printers.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you restart the CUPS daemon after you changed the config?

Comment: Yeah, the daemon got manually restarted then. The PC itself has also been restarted lots since as I'm just getting around to trying to fix the issue after several months.